# mysql find jobs in deptno 1 that are also in deptno 3

Tags: mysql

| empno | ename | job | mgr | hiredate | sal | comm | deptno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7369 | Smith | Clerk | 7902 | 1980-12-17 00:00:00 | 800 |  | 2 |
| 7499 | Allen | Salesman | 7698 | 1981-02-20 00:00:00 | 1600 | 300 | 3 |
| 7521 | Ward | Salesman | 7698 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 1250 | 500 | 3 |
| 7566 | Jones | Manager | 7839 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2975 |  | 2 |
| 7654 | Martin | Salesman | 7698 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 1250 | 1400 | 3 |
| 7698 | Blake | Manager | 7839 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2850 |  | 3 |
| 7782 | Clark | Manager | 7839 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2450 |  | 1 |
| 7788 | Scott | Analyst | 7566 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 3000 |  | 2 |
| 7839 | King | President |  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 5000 |  | 1 |
| 7844 | Turner | Salesman | 7698 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 1500 | 0 | 3 |
| 7876 | Adams | Clerk | 7788 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 1100 |  | 2 |
| 7900 | James | Clerk | 7698 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 950 |  | 3 |
| 7902 | Ford | Analyst | 7566 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 3000 |  | 2 |
| 7934 | Miller | Clerk | 7782 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 1300 |  | 1 |

I have this table.
Im looking to use sub-query to find employees in deptno1 with the same positions as in deptno3

So a realistic output should look like this:

| ename | job |
| --- | --- |
| Clark | Manager |
| Miller | Clerk |

I'm new to mysql, but i havent had any real difficulty until i reached subquery question, so if someone could briefly explain what it is, and how i can effectively use it, I would appreciate it very much.

This was my attempt at solving, but it doesnt work:

```
select ename, job from emp where deptno = (select deptno from emp where deptno = 1);
```

Comment: What does *with same positions* mean

Comment: Lets look at Miller, his job is Clerk. I should somehow ask mysql to look if someone else in deptno 3 has the same job as Miller. Dont know if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your query would be better expressed as

```
select ename, job 
from emp 
where depno = 1 and job in (select job from emp where deptno = 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self join

```
select t1.ename, t1.job 
from emp t1 
inner join emp t2 on t1.job = t2.job 
  and t1.deptno = 1 
  and t2.deptno = 3
```

Comment: what does the t1,t2 mean?

Comment: "The FROM table_references clause indicates the table or tables from which to retrieve rows. If you name more than one table, you are performing a join. For information on join syntax, see Section 13.2.10.2, “JOIN Clause”. For each table specified, you can optionally specify an alias."  (see: docs [select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html))

Comment: t1 and t2  are tablename alias  .. are used as refernce to the table  ..  in tgis way you can use the same table as two dfferent table

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT job FROM emp WHERE deptno = 3
```

returns all the `job`s in `deptno = 3` and you should use it in the `WHERE` clause of your query with the operator `IN` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT ename, job 
FROM emp 
WHERE deptno = 1
  AND job IN (SELECT job FROM emp WHERE deptno = 3);
```